# Computer won't boot after removing the SSD and putting it back in

Tags: windows-7, boot, ssd, reboot

Hello I had to remove my SSD last night and when I came to put it back in this morning and boot up it wouldn't ,I changed the boot order and set SSD first and now I can't do , my computer literally just is all day swiching it self off and on not showing anything but the fans and the leds. I have windows 7 installed on it.

It turns out one of my sticks of ram was faulty

Comment: Did you install windows 7 to this ssd?

Comment: Have you set it in right SATA port? Because if you installed windows without ACHI turned on on your motherboard this could be the problem.

Comment: Yes I have in stalled Windows 7 on it I have been usong this computer for about a month now I just happened to take my ssd out last night and put it back in today and it wont work

Comment: To indicate that your question has been resolved, you can [answer your own question](http://superuser.com/help/self-answer) and [accept it as the best answer](http://superuser.com/help/accepted-answer) by clicking on the "check" symbol below the voting controls. You do not need to edit the title of your question to indicate that it is resolved. See also: [Is it OK to add \[Solved\] to the title of a question?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/116101)

Answer (score 2):

Hmmm, this comes down to checking the basics.

1. Does it do the POST Beep? Or is it beeping multiple times, at what interval
2. Check to make sure your reset button is not stuck, this will make the pc constantly restart itself.
3. Did you put a CD / DVD in the ROM, if so remove it. One of the first signs that a PC's PSU is going is that it switches off / reboot cycles when putting a CD / DVD in.

But when you say all it does is switch on an off, does that mean that it starts up. And says it can't find a boot-able partition, and then restarts? Or does it not even display anything?

Another thing to note is that windows will install a boot partition on the primary drive, so if you installed windows with a old HDD plugged in and the SSD as a slave, then the boot partition (Boot Priority) would be that of the old HDD and not the SSD.

These are just some basic things to check, due to lack of info in your question.